# How to handle a division by zero in Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, divide-by-zero

In the following linq query I have a division by zero exception wich I can't seem to code around. It occurs when the Sum of fldDevider returns 0.

```
Dim lstToReturn As List(Of MonthData)

lstToReturn = (
 From myRow In dtSpotData.AsEnumerable()
 Group myRow By myRow.Field(Of DateTime)(fldstartdate).Month Into Group
 Select New MonthData() With {
 .Month = Month,
 .ValuePerMonth =
 (
  Group.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of [Decimal])(fldSomeGeneralValue)) /
  (
   Group.Sum(Function(dr) CDec(dr.Field(Of String)(fldDevider)))
  )
 )
 }
).ToList()
```

How can I Make sure the ValuePerMonth field is 0 when the Group.Sum(Function(dr) CDec(dr.Field(Of String)(fldDevider))) function returns a 0. Or how do I return a 1 for Sum fldDevider if it is actually 0.

Some tips on how to do better conversions from string to decimal are welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am used to C# syntax but I would use a 'let' to capture the value of the dividing number and only use it if it is greater than zero, and otherwise use 1.

```
Dim lstToReturn As List(Of MonthData)

lstToReturn = (
 From myRow In dtSpotData.AsEnumerable()
 Group myRow By myRow.Field(Of DateTime)(fldstartdate).Month Into Group
 Let div = Group.Sum(Function(dr) CDec(dr.Field(Of String)(fldDevider)))
 Select New MonthData() With {
 .Month = Month,
 .ValuePerMonth =
 (
  Group.Sum(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of [Decimal])(fldSomeGeneralValue)) / If(div > 0, div, 1)
 )
 }
).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really a hard question to find in the Linq documentation and examples.